# How to to decide the amount of max columns for a popup enumproperty?

Tags: python

I haven't found anything in the API, but I'm wondering if I can do this differently as well.
Really curious

```
import bpy

def my_enum_function(self,context):
    
    enum_list = []
    n = 0
    while n < 500:
        n+=1
        enum_list.append((str(n),str(n),""))

    return enum_list

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(scn.my_scene_prop,'my_enum',text="")
         
class ScenePropGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_enum: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items = my_enum_function)
    
classes = (
       LayoutDemoPanel,
       ScenePropGroup
       )

def register():
    for cls in classes:   
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.Scene.my_scene_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=ScenePropGroup)

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

It really seems that Blender decides how many items per columns, based on the size of the enum list.
It really feels like wasted space, but my thinking may be wrong and I need help from someone more experienced in this.

You can test easily by changing number `500` in the enum function

[image]